# Adding one day at each value change

Tags: r, datatable

I have a data.table with millions of rows in the following format.

There are multi-year results for each `ID`, however I only know the day of the year going from 1 to 365 or 366. I don't know the month nor the year, but I know the date for the first row (e.g. 1995/1/1).

```
ID    DAY   ATRR1   ATRR2
 1      1     0.2     0.4
 2      1     1.2     0.5
 3      1     0.8     1.4
 1      2     1.3     1.5
 2      2     2.3     0.3
 3      2     1.7     1.3
 1      3     1.5     1.4
 2      3     2.1     1.3
 3      3     1.2     0.3
  ...
 1    365     1.5     1.4
 2    365     2.1     1.3
 3    365     1.2     0.3
 1      1     1.5     1.4
 2      1     2.1     1.3
 3      1     1.2     0.3
 1      2     1.3     1.5
 2      2     2.3     0.3
 3      2     1.7     1.3
  ...
```

I would like to add a `DATE` column adding one day at each change in the `DAY` column, so the result would be:

```
ID    DAY   ATRR1   ATRR2        DATE
 1      1     0.2     0.4    1995/1/1
 2      1     1.2     0.5    1995/1/1
 3      1     0.8     1.4    1995/1/1
 1      2     1.3     1.5    1995/1/2
 2      2     2.3     0.3    1995/1/2
 3      2     1.7     1.3    1995/1/2
 1      3     1.5     1.4    1995/1/3
 2      3     2.1     1.3    1995/1/3
 3      3     1.2     0.3    1995/1/3
  ...
 1    365     1.5     1.4  1995/12/31
 2    365     2.1     1.3  1995/12/31
 3    365     1.2     0.3  1995/12/31
 1      1     1.5     1.4    1996/1/1
 2      1     2.1     1.3    1996/1/1
 3      1     1.2     0.3    1996/1/1
 1      2     1.3     1.5    1996/1/2
 2      2     2.3     0.3    1996/1/2
 3      2     1.7     1.3    1996/1/2
  ...
```

How would it be possible to do that?

Comment: Marc, can you post the dput(your.data.table)?

Comment: Do you have gaps in your `DAY` variable, or are there observations for every day of all years?

Comment: Hi, no there are no gaps at all. There are observations for every day of all years.

Comment: Henk: the table is far too big to post the dput() results..

Comment: dput(head(dt, 25) )

Comment: With dput(head(dt, 5) I got: structure(list(ID = 41:45, DAY = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), BASELINE = c(17.1523333333333, 
17.1523333333333, 17.1523333333333, 17.1023333333333, 17.0915
), SCENARIO1 = c(17.1555, 17.1555, 17.1555, 17.329, 17.329), SCENARIO2 = c(17.1105, 
17.0918333333333, 17.1031666666667, 17.2506666666667, 17.2538333333333
)), .Names = c("ID", "DAY", "BASELINE", "SCENARIO1", "SCENARIO2"
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x0000000000200788>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
as.Date(x, origin="1994-12-31")
```

My assumption here is that you don't have gaps in your dates and arranged as described in the question, otherwise this shall produce undesirable results.

**Sample data**:

```
df <- data.frame(Day = rep(c(1:365,1:2),each=3))
```

Create a `seq` like this using `rle`(run length encoding)

```
df$seq <- data.table::rleid(df$Day)
df$date <- as.Date(df$seq, origin="1994-12-31") #final answer
tail(df,8)
```

Let me know , if this is your expectation

**Sample Output:**

```
   > tail(df,8)
     Day seq       date
1094 365 365 1995-12-31
1095 365 365 1995-12-31
1096   1 366 1996-01-01
1097   1 366 1996-01-01
1098   1 366 1996-01-01
1099   2 367 1996-01-02
1100   2 367 1996-01-02
1101   2 367 1996-01-02
```

Answer (score 1):

date gaps no problem for this solution:

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
library(magrittr)

read.table(text = "
ID    DAY   ATRR1   ATRR2
1      1     0.2     0.4
2      1     1.2     0.5
3      1     0.8     1.4
1      2     1.3     1.5
2      2     2.3     0.3
3      2     1.7     1.3
1      3     1.5     1.4
2      3     2.1     1.3
3      3     1.2     0.3
1    365     1.5     1.4
2    365     2.1     1.3
3    365     1.2     0.3
1      1     1.5     1.4
2      1     2.1     1.3
3      1     1.2     0.3
1      2     1.3     1.5
2      2     2.3     0.3
3      2     1.7     1.3", header = T) %>% setDT -> x

x[, date := as.Date(DAY, origin = "1995-01-01") -1]
x[, date := {
  t1 = c(0, diff(DAY))
  t2 = ifelse(t1 < 0, 1, 0)
  t3 = cumsum(t2)
  t4 = date + years(t3)
  }]
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I got an error though... Error in date + years(t3) : 
  Arithmetic operators undefined for 'function' and 'Period' classes:
  convert one to numeric or a matching time-span class.

Comment: I have added the part where I read in your raw data. This works for me. Try a fresh R session. If this does not work, post str(x) and sessionInfo().